# Pythonic way to loop two lists

Tags: python, arrays, loops, for-loop

I have two arrays:

> ```
> Array_a = [20, 30, 50, 20]
> Array_b = [1 ,2  ,3  , 4]
> ```

would like to have the following output:

```
(20, '(1,Days Learning)') 
(30, '(2,Days Learning)') 
(50, '(3,Days Learning)') 
(20, '(4,Days Learning)')
```

My code looks like the following:

```
for i,j in zip(Array_a, Array_b):
    msg = (i, "(" + str(j) + ",Days Learning)")
    print(msg)
```

but I would like to have it somehow easier like the way:

```
for a, b in []
```

Comment: `res = [ (first, (second,'Days Learning')) for first, second in zip(Array_a, Array_b) ]` ?

Comment: OP, format your desired output please. Is it a `list` of `tuples` or what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one:

```
msg = [(a, '({}, Days Learning)'.format(b)) for a, b in zip(Array_a, Array_b)]
print(msg)
```

Will output:

```
[(20, '(1, Days Learning)'), (30, '(2, Days Learning)'), (50, '(3, Days Learning)'), (20, '(4, Days Learning)')]
```

## NOTE:

To print the elements line by line you can use `print` with `join` and another list-comprehension:

```
print('\n'.join(str(m) for m in msg))
```

Comment: doesn't get better than this imho. +1

Comment: you can also *exploit* `list-comprehensions` to just to the `print`ing for you like so: `[print(a, '({},Days Learning)'.format(b)) for a, b in zip(array_a, array_b)]`. Unassigned.

Comment: Yes, but it will also print a `list` populated with `None` objects. However you can do something like `print('\n'.join(str(m) for m in msg))`, which is a bit nicer in my opinion.

Comment: it will not `print` it. just create it and probably `garbage-collect` it soon after as no object will be pointing to it.

Comment: but sure, the `join()` is also nice

Comment: @Ev.Kounis you are right. By the way I won't prefer using `print` inside list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

How about this : 
it looks more pythonic way to me

```
Array_a = [20, 30, 50, 20]
Array_b = [1 ,2  ,3  , 4] 

sample = tuple(zip(Array_a,zip(Array_b,["Days Learning" for i in range(len(Array_b))])))
print(sample)
```

it will give you this result:

```
((20, (1, 'Days Learning')), (30, (2, 'Days Learning')), (50, (3, 'Days Learning')), (20, (4, 'Days Learning')))
```